# How do I use a remapping with solidity compiler?

Tags: solidity, compiler

If my contract is importing for example "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol", how do I make it work?

I know import_remappings is the option, but I just don't understand how I should use it.

I'm directly using python solcx, not brownie or truffle.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, share the configuration file you are using.